# How can I change Trash icon in unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, trash

I've changed so many icons individually by using `Main Menu`.
Now I want to change icons of Trash (empty and full trash) with some PNG but I don't know what to do.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Locate your trash.desktop file, and change the icon that way.  If you don't have a trash.desktop file, you can create one.  Open gedit, and include the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=user-trash
Name=Trash
GenericName=Trash
Comment=open trash in PCManFM
Categories=FileManager;Utility;Core;GTK;
Exec=pcmanfm trash:///
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-directory/normal;inode/directory;
```

Change the line `Icon=user-trash` with the location of your image.  Save as trash.desktop and exit.

Also you can look into `~/.icons` and `/usr/share/icons`,and change the icon that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm searching the desktop file. would not have to be two icons (full and empty trash)?

Comment: I was searching in both folders, and on differents subfolders (themes installed: ambiance, faenza,...) but I only found the icon of empty trash, I will test it, but where are the other? I cant found it.